# Removing a user from a text channel permission

Tags: javascript, discord

So is there a way I am able to remove a user from a text channel permission. So for instance I use a command on someone that disallows them to send messages and set SEND_MESSAGES to false then if I use the command again on the person instead of the permission being set to true to allow them to send messages again with the send messages permission has a green check mark under their name in the text channel permission. It just removes the user from the text channel permission and the text channel does not have the user under it anymore. I have Discord.js-v12.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you already understood that you can set PermissionOvewrites. Therefore you only need to delete a specific overwrite. To accomplish this, you simply have to call the [delete method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/PermissionOverwrites?scrollTo=delete).

Some example on how this could look like:

```
/**
* Remove permission overwrites for a member in a text channel.
* @param {GuildMember} member Member to remove permission overwrites from
* @param {TextChannel} textChannel Channel to remove permission overwrites from 
*/
function removeMemberPermOvewrite(member, textChannel) {
  const permissionOverwrite = textChannel.permissionOverwrites.get(member.id);
  if (permissionOverwrite) permissionOverwrite.delete().catch(console.error);
}
```

I also suggest that you update to v13. v12 will die out in the future and new features are only available if you use the latest version of discord.js.